# TaskDialogStandardIcon not working on task dialog

Tags: vb.net, taskdialog

I am creating a task dialog in vb.net and the icon is not coming up.(everything else works) i am using the Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs. my code is below:

```
 Dim commandLink_Send = New TaskDialogCommandLink("btnShowAlternatives", "View Alternative Times", "Select an available time")
    Dim commandLink_Ignore = New TaskDialogCommandLink("buttonIgnore", "Go Back", "Go back to booking form")
    **td.Icon = TaskDialogStandardIcon.Shield**
    td.Caption = "Application Error"
    td.InstructionText = "Booking Clash"
    td.Text = "The application has found a clash in one more of the selected resources"
    td.Cancelable = False
    td.Controls.Add(commandLink_Send)
    td.Controls.Add(commandLink_Ignore)
    AddHandler commandLink_Send.Click, AddressOf eventHandlers.commandLink_send_click
    AddHandler commandLink_Ignore.Click, AddressOf eventHandlers.commandLink_ignore_click
```

Am i doing something wrong

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, there's only 1 workaround for this.
You need to set it from the Opened event call.
Something like this:

```
AddHandler yourTD.opened, AddressOf yourTD_Opened
```

And somewhere add something like this:

```
Private Shared Sub yourTD_Opened(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    yourTD.icon = TaskDialogStandardIcon.Shield
    'And if you prefer you could also
    'yourTD.FooterIcon = TaskDialogStandardIcon.whichevericonyouwant
End Sub
```

CHeers.

Comment: If you came here looking for c# code like I did:

taskDialog.Opened += delegate { taskDialog.Icon = TaskDialogStandardIcon.Error; };