# How to add an icon to the title of messagebox in VB.NET 2010

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010, messagebox, msgbox

I tried to add an icon to the title of the messagebox. I researched at web, but I can't find a good answer. How do I add an icon to the title of the messagebox?

Look to this messagebox:

[image: A messagebox picture with an icon at its title]

I tried msgbox and messagebox.show but I can't find how to add an icon to the title.

Can someone help me? I am using Visual Basic 2010.

Comment: Can you show the code you've tried?

Comment: I tried this:  MessageBox.Show("Example Messagebox", "Messagebox", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information)  but the icon only visible at inside of the messagebox. Is there a way to add the icon to the title?

Comment: It seems you need TaskDialog class (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.taskdialog). See https://learn.microsoft.com/sk-sk/windows/win32/controls/task-dialogs-overview for more info. If not available in VS 2010, you can try pinvoke or WindowsAPICodePack, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15645592/